# Howto htaccess RewriteRule Browser Language redirect for Dutch NL users (Multiple Domains)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to enforce a Browser Language redirect for Dutch users. But I want this for Dutch users ONLY, that's why I am NOT using the WPML feature.

What's wrong with the 3 htaccess lines below? I even threw away all other lines in htaccess to be sure that there wasn't something interfering. I get the error "This webpage has a redirect loop" in Chrome.

I have a multi domain setup, .com for English, .nl for Dutch, .de for German, .fr for French, etc.

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (nl) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.nl/$1 [R,L]

Your help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found this example on http://htaccess.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/allow-block-country-htaccess/:

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

# Redirect one country
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CA$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.canada.com$1 [L]

# Redirect multiple countries to a single page
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(CA|US|MX)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.northamerica.com$1 [L]
```